# How to handle JPA exceptions when two fields of an entity are (unique = true)?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Let's say I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accounts")
public class AccountImpl implements Account {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
  private String email;

  @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
  private String username;

  // constructor + getters

}
```

The email and username fields are set to unique. Now, if an object is being created with a duplicate email or username of another object, JPA will throw Persistence Exception. How can I create separate handlers for dealing with duplicate email and username?

```
    Account account = new AccountImpl(email, username, password, role);
    try {
        service.createAccount(account);
    } catch(javax.persistence.PersistenceException e) {
        addFieldError("username", "Username taken");

        // Oh crap! What if the exception has been thrown by email?

        return INPUT;
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: That should not be done on the service layer rather should be done on the web layer, if it is a web application. Do a search to see, if an entry already exists in the database before the operation itself propagates to the service layer and throws an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to before do `createAccount` do a search based on the `username` if it returns a record then which means the `username` is already taken return appropriate message, also u could so the same thing for `email`.

If both the search returns `none` then u know its a new account, and execute `createAccount`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but wouldn't that slow down my apps performance?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can check for duplicates before trying to persist an object, and based on the result, return proper error, or persist the object...